# How to implement multi typed elements in single page with single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typed, typedjs

I am a trying to two divs (that use stringElements) on the page that share the same class in [**typed.js**](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js), so far only the first occurence gets working.

Here, It is possible with 2 different function with different class. but, I want to it with single function with same class.

Here show you what i'm trying to do. https://jsfiddle.net/xbofduaz/

What would be the proper way for that.

```
var typed1 = new Typed('.typed', {
  stringsElement: '.typed-strings',
  loop: true,
  typeSpeed: 50,
  backSpeed: 20,
  backDelay: 1700,
  showCursor: false,
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>TypedJS on multiple identical stringElements on the page</h1>

  <div class="typed-strings">
    <p>Ice cream</p>
    <p>Moog synth</p>
    <p>Holidays in space</p>
  </div>
  <span class="typed"></span>

  <p> Some other stuff on the page goes on, until we uncounter the exact same typed strings, that I also want to animate (and tarket thanks to a class). To note that both of these similar blocks come from the database, I'm unable to duplicate them to change their class or id, I need them to be exactly the same, and both be animated. </p>

  <div class="typed-strings">
    <p>Ice cream</p>
    <p>Moog synth</p>
    <p>Holidays in space</p>
  </div>
  <span class="typed"></span> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that `document.querySelector()` is used in the [load method](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/950d4527ce82c565cf248961f7c476ed7d225ae7/lib/typed.js#L610) of `typedjs`. So multiple elements cant be constructed. Try using `querySelectorAll()`

```
document.querySelectorAll('.typed').forEach(function(el) {
    new Typed(el, {
    stringsElement: el.previousElementSibling,
    loop: true,
    typeSpeed: 50,
    backSpeed: 20,
    backDelay: 1700,
    showCursor: false,
  })
});
```

**Working Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/ebjzmLur/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but, this is not working properly. does first typed-strings text call in both. you will realize when we use different text. please check this - https://jsfiddle.net/e827rao1/